# Firebase subcollection structure

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm starting to practice using Firestore subcollections after only using realtime database and the 'basic' `Firestore .add{()}` function. I created multiple subcollections within my "Posts" group and tried calling them. I've looked around multiple youtube videos, websites and SoF posts but neither got anything to display. I'm trying to store message post information in multiple threads like this [image]

Along with that, I've also tried using the normal .add function,  rearranging my `docRef.collection("Posts").doc().collection("burgers")` in multiple different ways and nothing worked.

In order to get it to actually show up, I need to put the specific doc id like this docRef.collection("Posts").doc("hd7oasdgaasdjabdjj").collection("burgers") but this isn't practical for more than one subcollection.

Can I get some advice on a different structure to use or something I made a mistake on?

Comment: "the collection error I got" What error is that? Can you edit your question to include the error message and (if available) stack trace, and the code that produces that error?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my bad, fixed it :). The code that gave me an error is in the last paragraph, "docRef.collection("Posts").doc().collection("burgers")"

Comment: That last comment is unclear; did you figure out the answer or was that meaning you included the information we requested? If you still need help, let us know

Comment: @Jay the error was just that nothing loaded. I think I figured something out, is there some sort of limit if I stored a large amount of data in a subcollection?

Comment: No. The current issue is the code you're using has no meaning `docRef.collection("Posts").doc()` <- doc doesn't do anything in this case. You need to specify *which* doc you're attempting to access. You mentioned that in your question but then said it isn't practical. Why not? The issue you're having isn't clear. Also *I created multiple subcollections within my "Posts" group* - your Posts COLLECTION (not group) has no sub-collections. It has DOCUMENTS and the documents have sub-collections. Firestore structure is always *collection/document/collection/document* in pairs

Comment: @Jay alright thank you! :)